# Is it possible to force logout using user id in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm wondering if there is any simple way to force logout different users by their id? For example I need to block currently lodged in user so I want to log out him after I set his status to block.

P.S.
I cant use middleware for this to check on each request.

Comment: Why can't you use a middleware?

Comment: @PeterPan666 because project is very big and checking each request for blocked user will cost some performance. i'm already checking blocked status on login.

Answer (score 14):

I do this inside the Authenticate middleware

```
if (!Auth::user()->isActive()) {
    Auth::logout();

    return Redirect::home();
}
```

The user is already loaded there, no additional database query is needed here.

I don't think that's a performance issue, you just do a little if statement and you do it only if the user needs to be authenticated.

Comment: how do you do this in laravel 5.4. the auth middleware is now in `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`. do i create and copy it in `/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` and add my conditional statement?

Comment: You can do a LogoutDisableUser middleware and call it before the auth middleware and even create a group called "auth" and call the logout inactive then the auth middleware inside ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's super easy if you are using database session driver:

```
DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $userId)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using later Laravel 5.6+, there's a method available for this built in. Doesn't mention where to call `logoutOtherDevices`, but LoginController@authenticated looks to work well as you can pass through their password, as required by the method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->get('password'));
```